# How to define variable with namespace in EL processor?

Tags: java, el, el-processor

In some XML files I saw something like this `<tag attr="${sys:com.foo.bar}"/>` where it is meant that `${sys:com.foo.bar}` will be replaced to `System.getProperty("com.foo.bar")`.

I want my EL processor to support such feature. However, I can't find how to do it.

```
ELProcessor elProcessor = new ELProcessor();
elProcessor. ???
```

The only method that has prefix is `defineFunction`, but as I understand this is not what I need:

```
this.elProcessor.defineFunction(prefix, function, method);
this.elProcessor.defineFunction(prefix, function, className, method);
```

Could anyone say how to make my EL processor to work with variables with namespaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've undoubtedly seen this in Maven / Spring / Log4j related XML configuration files. Unfortunately, they don't use Jakarta EL to resolve them. They use under the covers [Apache Commons Text `StringSubstitutor`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringSubstitutor.html) for this. And, Jakarta EL doesn't support this [syntax](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/expression-language/5.0/jakarta-expression-language-spec-5.0#syntax-restrictions) in first place. It would already die with a syntax error before even having the chance to hit any custom EL listener or EL resolver.

With Jakarta EL, your best bet is to change the syntax to `${sys['com.foo.bar']}` and add a custom [`ELResolver`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/10/apidocs/jakarta/el/elresolver) which recognizes `${sys}` as a special kind of base and then resolves the rest via [`System#getProperty()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#getProperty(java.lang.String)).

Here's a kickoff working example of such EL resolver:

```java
public class SystemPropertyELResolver extends ELResolver {

    @Override
    public Class<?> getCommonPropertyType(ELContext context, Object base) {
        return (base == this) ? String.class : null;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getType(ELContext context, Object base, Object property) {
        if (base == null && "sys".equals(property)) {
            context.setPropertyResolved(true);
            return getClass();
        }
        else if (base == this && property != null) {
            context.setPropertyResolved(true);
            return getCommonPropertyType(context, base);
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValue(ELContext context, Object base, Object property) {
        if (base == null && "sys".equals(property)) {
            context.setPropertyResolved(true);
            return this;
        }
        else if (base == this && property != null) {
            context.setPropertyResolved(true);
            return System.getProperty(property.toString());
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(ELContext context, Object base, Object property, Object val) {
        // NOOP.
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isReadOnly(ELContext context, Object base, Object property) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<FeatureDescriptor> getFeatureDescriptors(ELContext context, Object base) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

In order to get it to run, register it as follows:

```java
elProcessor.getELManager().addELResolver(new SystemPropertyELResolver());
```

---

However, in the *specific* case of `System#getProperty()`, there's another, yet simpler, way to "define a variable with namespace". As [`System#getProperties()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#getProperties()) already returns an instance of  `java.util.Map`, the built-in [`jakarta.el.MapELResolver`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/10/apidocs/jakarta/el/mapelresolver) could be used to take care of it while using the same syntax of `${sys['com.foo.bar']}`.

```java
elProcessor.defineBean("sys", System.getProperties());
```

This only doesn't offer you the opportunity to further customize the EL resolving.

Comment: What you suggest `${sys['com.foo.bar']}` is what I am doing now. But to get it I do: `this.eLProcessor.defineBean("sys", System.getProperties())`.

Comment: Of course! That's also a way, I was overthinking a bit :)

Comment: Log4j2 supports such syntax - https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html#system-properties-lookup But I can't understand what EL processor they use - https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/rel/2.21.1/log4j-core/pom.xml

Comment: They use (a copy of) Apache Commons Text `StringSubstitor`: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringSubstitutor.html